# Nest 5.6 - How to insert a document with already existing id?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the following code:

```
IIndexResponse response = elclient.Index(appointmentHistoryRecord, i => i.Index(OperaIndexName)
                                                                         .Type(appointmentHistoryRecord.GetType())
                                                                         .Id(appointmentHistoryRecord.AppointmentId.ToString())
                                                                         .Refresh(Refresh.False));
```

The above code works just fine, but it doesn't behave how I want it to behave. What I'm trying to accomplish is insert a document with an id that already exists in the index. The new document will have the same id, but a different body.

The code I've written will take the existing document and update it with the new body, which is something I'm trying to avoid. I want to have a new record in the index despite the document having a matching id in the index.

Any help on how I can accomplish that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have 2 documents with the same id for obvious raison.
id is a Key.

You can upsert: create a document if doesn't exist, update if it exists.
update: update an existing document
partial update: update a part of an existing document.

You can of course create a document with a my_field_id field (who is not the id of the document) and insert 0-X documents with the same my_field_id value.

I don't really understand why you try to duplicate a document, maybe explain your context and we will try to find a good modelisation or a solution.

**Edit from second answer**

Ok so instead of use the elasticsearch id (=key field) add a field(= your entityid i think) in your document, and just insert the document without set the id field (lets es generate a id for you). Then use entityid field to retrieve all the document related to your entity (hope i am clear :)), share your mappings if you need help and i will update it.

Happy it s help you ;)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I'm trying to log every activity done to an entity and since the entity is always the same, but with different values, that's the reason I'm trying to insert a document with a duplicate id.

Comment: Ok so instead of use the elasticsearch id (=key field) add a field(= your entityid i thinck) in your document, and just insert the document without set the id field (lets es generate a id for you). Then use entityid field to retrieve all the document related to your entity (hope i am clear :)), share your mappings if you need help and i will update it.

Comment: Hello, I've written my queries in a way that you suggested and it worked fine, thank you very much. You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the elasticsearch id (=key field) add a field (= your entityid I think) in your document, and just insert the document without setting the id field (lets ES generate an id for you). Then use the entityid field to retrieve all the document related to your entity.